# How to do implement this relationship with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on ember.js Project, which is backed by a Rails 4 API.

Now i've this relationship where i'm not really sure how to implement it with ember-data.

I have two Models: User and Event

User can create Events, so there is a 1-n relationship between creator and event
User can attend to Events, so there is a m-n relationship between attendees and events

The creator-event relationship will be returned by the API as creator_id on the events and as event_ids on the creator.

The attendees-events relationship will be returned by the API as attendee_ids on the events and as attended_event_ids on the attendees.

Now, ember-data supports many-to-many relation by adding hasMany relations on both ends of the relation.

```
# App.User
events: DS.hasMany('App.Event')
attended_events: DS.hasMany('App.Event')

# App.Event
creator: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
attendees: DS.hasMany('App.User')
```

My problem is, how do i tell ember-data that attendees related to attended_events and creator relates to events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, never mind, i figured it out myself, this seem to work:

```
# App.User
events: DS.hasMany('App.Event', as: 'creator')
attended_events: DS.hasMany('App.Event', as: 'attendees')

# App.Event
creator: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
attendees: DS.hasMany('App.User')
```